# Problema con paginacion en php

Tags: javascript, php

Armé un paginador muy rudimentario, al entrar a mi `index.php` pagina una consulta de todos los registros. Para ello solo le paso por url el número de pagina a mostrar y recargo la misma página, cual funciona.

Ahora me surgió la necesidad de mostrar y paginar los registros por categoría. Puse un select en mi index.php y al elegir categoría le paso categoria + '1' a otra pagina llamada `categoria.php` donde tengo las mismas funciones que en mi index (copio como paso este valor ) :

```
<select id="combo_categorias" name="cat" onchange="location.href='categoria.php?num=' + this.value +'1';">
```

Mando por url el valor de la categoría que es un string , ej.: 'zapateria' + un 1, ya que la primera pagina a visualizar es siempre la 1 .

El tema es que ya parado en `categoria.php`, cuando tengo paginada mas de 1 página no me funciona , puedo pasar el valor de la pagina .. pero se pierde el valor de la categoria y no encuentro la forma de solucionarlo .
Copio el código :

```
   <?php  
        $variable=" ";
        $rest=" ";
        $restvar=" ";

        //Si lo recibido por GET
        if (isset($_GET['num'])) {
            $variable=$_GET['num'];
        }

        //Saco del GET el último dígito
            $rest=substr($variable, -1);

        //Saco todo menos el último dígito
            $restvar=substr($variable, 0, -1);

        //Convierto lo sustraído en la variable
            $variable=$restvar;
//            $_SESSION["cat_elegida"]=$variable;
    ?>

    <div class="pagina">
        <?php include ("cabecera.php"); ?>
            <div class="contenedor">
                    <div class="productos">
        <?php

        $consulta="select * from productos where categoria LIKE '$variable' ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
        $nro_reg = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($nro_reg==0) {
            ?>    
                <div class="superado_stock">    
                <?php
                    echo "<h4> </h4>";
                    echo "<h4><strong>Producto temporalmente agotado</strong></h4>";
                    echo "<h4> </h4>";
                ?>
                </div>                               
                <?php
            }

        $reg_por_pagina=12;

        if (isset($_GET['num'])) {
            $nro_pagina=$rest;
            var_dump($nro_pagina);
            var_dump($variable);
        } else {
            $nro_pagina=1;
        }

        if (is_numeric($nro_pagina))
            $inicio=(($nro_pagina-1)*$reg_por_pagina);
        else
            $inicio=0;

        $consulta=mysqli_query($con,"select * from productos where categoria LIKE '$variable' order by id ASC limit $inicio, $reg_por_pagina");
        $canti_paginas=ceil($nro_reg/$reg_por_pagina);
        ?>
        <?php
            while ($filas=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo mysql_error();
                $id=$filas['id'];
                $imagen=$filas['imagen'];
                $nombre=$filas['nombre'];
                $descripcion=$filas['descripcion'];
                $precio=$filas['precio'];
                $stock=$filas['stock'];
                $fecha=$filas['fecha'];
                if($imagen=="No disponible"){
                    $imagen="IMAGENES/ImagenNoDisponible100.gif";
                }                
        ?>

            <div class="caja">
                <div class="caja_imagen"><img src="<?php echo $imagen?>" style=widht="100" height="100"/>
                        <p class="caja_nombre"><?php echo $nombre?></p>
                        <p class="caja_precio">$ <?php echo $precio?></p>
                </div>   
                <div class="caja_boton">
                    <form action="detalle.php" method="post" name="detalle">
                        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
                        <input class="boton_detalle2" type="submit" value="Detalle">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
       <?php
            }
        ?>
            </div>
        </div>       
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <!-----------------------------PAGINADOR------------------------------------------------------>
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->      

            <div id="paginador" align="center">
                        <?php
                        if ($nro_pagina>1)
                            echo "<a href='categoria.php?num=".($nro_pagina-1) ."' >Anterior</a> ";

                        for ($i=1;$i<=$canti_paginas;$i++){

                            if ($i==$nro_pagina)
                                echo "<span>$i </span>" ;
                            else
                                echo "<a href='categoria.php?num=$i'>$i</a> ";
                        }

                        if ($nro_pagina<$canti_paginas)
                            echo "<a href='categoria.php?num=". ($nro_pagina+1) ."' >Siguiente</a> ";
                        ?>
            </div>
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <!--------------------------FIN DEL PAGINADOR------------------------------------------------->
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->   
        </div>   
    </div>
```

Quizás pudiera pasar 2 valores x url , pero no lo logro.

Comment: Bueno , recien logré solucionarlo , en la pagina categorias cree una variable de session con la categoria , y un nuevo valor num2 que es el que paso x url . Quedó ok , disculpen si los hago leer . Obvio si alguien aporta una mejora viene muy bien. Graciassss

Comment: Me alegro mucho que hayas resuelto tu pregunta. Sin embargo, ponla con detalle abajo como respuesta en vez de como comentario. De esta manera es mucho más fácil que la gente la vea y le pueda ser útil. Además, en 2 días la podrás marcar como aceptada :)

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas sesiones, simplemente pasa las dos variables al script, por ejemplo así:

```html
<select id="combo_categorias" name="cat" onchange="location.href='categoria.php?cat=' + this.value + '&num=1';">
```

Y ya en tu script categoría.php, algo como esto (he hecho la edición acá mismo, así que puede que el código tenga errores, pero te da la idea de a donde quiero llegar:

```html
<?php  
    $categoria = isset($_GET['cat'])?$_GET['cat']:"%";
    $categoria = mysqli_real_escape_string($categoria);
    $num = isset($_GET['num'])?$_GET['num']:"1";
    if (!is_numeric($num)) {
        $num = "1";
    }
?>
   
<div class="pagina">
    <?php include ("cabecera.php"); ?>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="productos">
    <?php
        $consulta="select * from productos where categoria LIKE '$categoria' ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
        $nro_reg = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        
        if ($nro_reg==0) {
    ?>    
                <div class="superado_stock">    
                    <h4> </h4>
                    <h4><strong>Producto temporalmente agotado</strong></h4>
                    <h4> </h4>
                </div>                               
    <?php
        }
                        
        $reg_por_pagina=12;
        
        $inicio=(($num - 1) * $reg_por_pagina);
        
        $consulta=mysqli_query($con,"select * from productos where categoria LIKE '$categoria' order by id ASC limit $inicio, $reg_por_pagina");
        $canti_paginas=ceil($nro_reg/$reg_por_pagina);
        while ($filas=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo mysql_error();
            $id=$filas['id'];
            $imagen=$filas['imagen'];
            $nombre=$filas['nombre'];
            $descripcion=$filas['descripcion'];
            $precio=$filas['precio'];
            $stock=$filas['stock'];
            $fecha=$filas['fecha'];
            if($imagen=="No disponible"){
                $imagen="IMAGENES/ImagenNoDisponible100.gif";
            }                
    ?>
        
            <div class="caja">
                <div class="caja_imagen"><img src="<?php echo $imagen?>" style=widht="100" height="100"/>
                        <p class="caja_nombre"><?php echo $nombre?></p>
                        <p class="caja_precio">$ <?php echo $precio?></p>
                </div>   
                <div class="caja_boton">
                    <form action="detalle.php" method="post" name="detalle">
                        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
                        <input class="boton_detalle2" type="submit" value="Detalle">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
            </div>
        </div>       
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <!-----------------------------PAGINADOR------------------------------------------------------>
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->      

            <div id="paginador" align="center">
    <?php
        if ($num>1)
          echo "<a href='categoria.php?cat=$categoria&num=".($num-1) ."'>Anterior</a>";

        for ($i=1;$i<=$canti_paginas;$i++){

            if ($i==$nro_pagina)
                echo "<span>$i </span>" ;
            else
                echo "<a href='categoria.php?cat=$categoria&num=$i'>$i</a>";
        }
                
        if ($num<$canti_paginas)
            echo "<a href='categoria.php?cat=&categoria&num=". ($nro_pagina+1) ."' >Siguiente</a>";
    ?>
            </div>
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <!--------------------------FIN DEL PAGINADOR------------------------------------------------->
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->   
        </div>   
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
desde el controlador:

```
        //Limito la busqueda 
        $pagination = 1; 
        //examino la página a mostrar y el inicio del registro a mostrar 
        $page = 1;
        $start = 0;

        if(isset($_GET["page"])){
            $page = $_GET["page"];
            $start = ($page - 1) * $pagination;
        }

        //veo el número total de campos que hay en la tabla con esa búsqueda 
        $total_rows = $this->db->get('datos_estudiante');
        //echo count($total_rows);

        //calculo el total de páginas 
        $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $pagination); 
        /*//pongo el número de registros total, el tamaño de página y la página que se muestra 
        echo "Número de registros encontrados: " . $total_rows . "<br>"; 
        echo "Se muestran páginas de " . $pagination . " registros cada una<br>"; 
        echo "Mostrando la página " . $page . " de " . $total_pages . "<p>";*/

        //muestro los distintos índices de las páginas, si es que hay varias páginas 
        if ($total_pages > 1){ 
            for ($i = 1;$i <= $total_pages; $i++){ 
               if ($page.'?' == $i){
                  //si muestro el índice de la página actual, no coloco enlace 
                  $current .= '<li class="active"><a>'.$page.'</a></li> '; 
                } else {
                  //si el índice no corresponde con la página mostrada actualmente, coloco el enlace para ir a esa página 
                  $next .= '<li><a href="'.base_url('').'datos_estudiante/index/?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li> '; 
                }
            } 
        }
        //$this->input->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT');

        $data['titulo'] = 'Bienvenido';
        $data['query'] = $this->Model_Datos_Estudiante->all_paginate($start, $pagination);
        $data['contenido'] = 'datos_estudiante/index';
        $data['paginate'] = $current.$next;
        $data['data'] = $data;
        $this->load->view('template/template',$data);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Desde el modelo:

```
public function all_paginate($start, $pagination){
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM datos_estudiante LIMIT '.$start.','.$pagination);
    return $query;
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Desde la vista:

```
<?php foreach($query as $registro): ?>
   ACA VAN LOS DATOS
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

- 

Comment: Buenas. Para que sea un respuesta válida explica tambien tu codigo.